# How do you use a function to add an array with its key values?

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array

I am very new at php so I am pretty certain my syntax is wrong. I also understand it is probably better to simply add to the array but my question is more for learning purposes:

Here's my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    // list of players
    $currentPlayers = array(
        "player1" => array(
            "name"   => "Ryan",
            "age"    => 26,
            "weight" => 200,
        ),
    );
    // function to add a new person
    function addPlayer($nextPlayer, $name, $age, $weight) {
        $currentPlayers[$nextPlayer]["name"] = $name;
        $currentPlayers[$nextPlayer]["age"] = $age;
        $currentPlayers[$nextPlayer]["weight"] = $weight;
    }
    addPlayer("player2", "Joe", 23, 180);
    echo $currentPlayers["player2"]["name"];
?>
```

Comment: Please explain in your question what isn't working. What warning or error messages are you getting? What have you tried to investigate the problem?

Comment: It looks like there is something faulty in my logic even after importing the variable $currentPlayers using global. I don't get an error code, just a blank browser when it doesn't run. I'm using mamp.

Comment: I recommend enabling `E_NOTICE` and other warning output to see why it's not working. If you don't have access to the `php.ini` used on the server then put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$currentPlayers` is undefined within the scope of `addPlayer`, you need to import it by changing your function's signature to this:

```
function addPlayer($nextPlayer, $name, $age, $weight) {
    globals $currentPlayers;

    // logic here
}
```

an alternative (because PHP loves to have more than one way of doing something):

```
function addPlayer($nextPlayer, $name, $age, $weight) {
    $currentPlayers = $GLOBALS['currentPlayers'];

    // logic here
}
```

Comment: I see that your answer was voted up 4 times. Is it better practice than the one I accepted? If so, how would you change the logic along with your answer to make it work?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the script you posted in your question that would cause it to abort during script processing. Something else must be wrong. I suggest enabling `E_ALL` to help investigate the problem.

Comment: Did more troubleshooting, I made a syntax error. Thank you for your answer, although the other one works, I think that you best answered my question so I'm checking this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in following way:

function addPlayer(&$currentPlayers,$nextPlayer, $name, $age, $weight) {
}

addPlayer($currentPlayers,"player2", "Joe", 23, 180);

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here for more information about variable scope.

If you want to do it with a function, this would work, too:

```
$currentPlayers = array(
    "player1" => array(
        "name"   => "Ryan",
        "age"    => 26,
        "weight" => 200,
    ),
);
// function to add a new person
function addPlayer($name, $age, $weight) {
    return array("name" => $name, "age" => $age, "weight" => $weight);
}
$currentPlayers["player2"] = addPlayer("Joe", 23, 180);
echo $currentPlayers["player2"]["name"];
```